# How to implement full text search in Mongo Mapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, mongomapper

I need to implement full text search in mongomapper model. I have tried mongomapper_search gem but it didn't work for me. I didn't got any results from it. Is there any other gem available for such functionality ?

Comment: unless you're doing crazy stuff with MongoDB which you shouldn't because it doesn't support native full text search you can use regex to search your strings. Example: `string = User.all(:comment => /#{Regexp.escape(search_term)}/i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a guess -- but when you first install a full text engine, you need to create your index. I looked over the [mongomapper_search code](https://github.com/mariopeixoto/mongomapper_search/blob/master/lib/mongomapper_search/search.rb), and see the following command (say for Product)

```
Product.index_keywords!
```

Try running that on your models, then performing your search.

Comment: Thanx buddy. I agree on that. I had to generate indexes for all the available data. I found one more gem which is doing the same thing. At its really nice. Sharing it with you for your reference also. Gem name is "hunt".